# Speed up List.fold with Threads and Channels

Tags: multithreading, list, ocaml, channel

What I am trying to achieve is, my own version of `List.fold_right` or `List.fold_left` with `Event Module` and `Thread Module` in order to speed up the process.

(I'm aware that Ocaml doesn't support parallel multithreading, but I'm in here for the concept)

My try : (although I'm not sure I won extra time)

```
open Thread
open Event
let rec tapply f start = function
  | [] -> start
  | h::t -> let c = new_channel () in
            let _ = create (fun _ -> sync (send c (f h (tapply f start t)))) () 
            in sync (receive c)
```

Calling `tapply` :

`#tapply ( * ) 1 [1;2;3;4];;
- : int = 24`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to parallelize fold functions in the general case, as every intermediate value is dependent on all the previous ones. See [Cipher Block Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29), for example. Parallelization is possible if certain additional conditions are met.

Example 1: If it's possible to treat each list element as a function (example: group actions), then you can exploit the associativity of functions using a divide and conquer approach, where you first calculate the function represented by a list and then apply it to the initial element.

Example 2: If the function is commutative and you're using reduce instead of a fold operation, then you can split the list into sublists and distribute work for the sublists, such as:

```
open Batteries

let par_reduce n f l =
  (* worker thread *)
  let worker (ch, l) =
    List.reduce f l |> Event.(sync % send ch) in
  (* split [l] in [n] sublists *)
  let k = max (List.length l / n) 1 in
  let sublists = List.ntake k l in
  (* create [n] worker threads *)
  List.map (fun sublist ->
    let ch = Event.new_channel () in
    let _ = Thread.create worker (ch, sublist) in
    ch) sublists
  (* collect results *)
  |> List.map Event.(sync % receive)
  (* and combine those into the final result *)
  |> List.reduce f

let factorial n =
  par_reduce 4 Num.mult_num (List.init n (fun k -> Num.of_int (k+1)))

let () =
  Printf.printf "%s\n" Num.(to_string @@ factorial 1000)
```

Note 1: This uses the "batteries included" library for some convenience functions.

Note 2: There are faster ways to calculate large factorials – in fact, the code doesn't even split the work evenly –, this is just an example that actually uses some CPU time.